# shuffle url parameter behind & in Perl

Tags: perl, shuffle

Hello i was wondering if anyone know how to shuffle an url with perl, but then only all parameters after the `&`.

here's an example:

`anyurl=i&ct=1&cad=1&rsm=6&ei=JthyULClH8fH0QWcooD4Bw&zx=1349703728841`

here's what im looking for:

`anyurl=i&ei=JthyULClH8fH0QWcooD4Bw&cad=1&ct=1&rsm=6&zx=1349703728841`

just so that all parameters behind the & are placed on a different place randomly. So i want all parameters behind the `&` on a different place every print, is this possible?

thnx in advance.

Comment: `split(/&/, ...)` everything at the `&` to a list, invoke [shuffle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-shuffle-an-array-randomly?) and join the list again again by `&`.

Comment: Use 'rubber boot's idea and create some Perl code. You'll get much better answers if you show us what you've tried.

Comment: you should accept one of the answers, it will bump your votes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $url = 'http://www.anyurl.com/userdata?ct=1&cad=1&rsm=6&ei=JthyULClH8fH0QWcooD4Bw&zx=1349703728841';
my @parts = split(/\?/,$url);
my $parms = join('&',shuffle(split(/&/,$parts[1])));
my $shuffled = join('?',$parts[0],$parms);

print $shuffled;
```

can be shorter, but this is a step-by-step idea of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the query string into an array and then shuffling the array:

```
my $qryStr = 'ct=1&cad=1&rsm=6&ei=JthyULClH8fH0QWcooD4Bw&zx=1349703728841';

my @init = split('&', $qryStr);

my $i = @init;

my @shfld;

while($i--)
{
        my $j = int(rand($i+1));

        $shfld[$i] = $init[$j];
        splice(@init, $j, 1);
}

my $rslt = join('&', @shfld);

print "\nRESULT = ".$rslt;
```